# How to style a blurred, centered and responsive box for a login form with full size background?

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive

I have tried to build a login form  on a HTML page (Angular) that has a full size, centered background image and the form is placed in a div with blurred background, that is centered in the x- and y-axis of the browser window.

That is how far I came: https://codepen.io/surfermicha/pen/ZwpxBa

```
<div class="login-background-door2">
  <div class="aero-background centered">
    <h3>Here will be a login form later</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately i have some issues with that:

1. The centered box isn't exactly in the center
2. It's not responsive. The div is to small at small devices. I want 10px margin left and right, but a max-width 500px on bigger screens.

Could anyone help edit the codepen for a working responsive solution

Comment: its exectly center bro

Comment: hm you are right... But it was when I set position to relative. i changed that.

Comment: so what you want ? from our side

Comment: how to center it that it has on small screens the same margin (10px) when you look at the codepen it has left more space then right

Comment: first of all add position absolute in your .centered class

Comment: give media queries to solve that things

Comment: ok. How would you solve this? (I'm not so familiar to meda queries)

Comment: Sorry for newbe question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187503/discussion-between-nisharg-shah-and-michael-l).

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do pretty much anything you can do on codepen here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set media queries by your needs, like I set into 567px because after 567px view of your center block, don't look nice so I set into 567px.

```css
body, html {
  font-family: "roboto", monospace;
  color: #EEE;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.aero-background::before {
  content: '';
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/2400/2000") center no-repeat;
  filter: blur(6px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.aero-background {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

.centered {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.login-background-door2 {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/2400/2000") center no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 567px) {
  .centered {
    width: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="login-background-door2">
  <div class="aero-background centered">
    <h3>Here will be a login form later</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLjXgW

Centered with flex, no media queries

```css
body, html {
  font-family: "roboto", monospace;
  color: #EEE;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

$login-background-image: "http://placekitten.com/2400/2000";

.aero-background::before{
  content: '';
  background: url($login-background-image)  center no-repeat;
  filter: blur(6px);
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.aero-background {
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(black, .4);
  border:1px solid rgba(white,.1);
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow:0 0 10px black;
  max-width:500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.login-background-door2 {
  background: url($login-background-image) center no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-background-door2">
  <div class="aero-background">
    <h3>Here will be a login form later</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

My first time answering so I apologize if missed something

Comment: bro, there is no discussion about center, we are taking about 2nd problem

Comment: Which is also solved in the proposed solution: responsive, with 10px margin on both sides, even on smaller screens and max-width of 500px for larger screens